# How compiler handles symbolic constants in enumerations?

Tags: c, enums, macros, constants, enumeration

If we talk about macros than compiler handles them during preprocessing stage but what about enumerators. How compiler sees them. For example see the below code :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
enum day {sunday = 1, monday, tuesday = 5, 
        wednesday, thursday = 10, friday, saturday}; 

int main() 
{ 
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", sunday, monday, tuesday, 
            wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday); 
    return 0; 
}
```

In this particular example, I have not even created any variable for enumerated data type. I am simply using the `enumeration-constants` in my `printf()` statement. Do enumerators work similar to macros internally ? Will all these symbolic constants be replaced by there integer constants during preprocessing ? How exactly compiler handles them ?

Comment: FYI: `enum` related stuff does not get changed in any way by the preprocessor (unless you use a regular macro)

Comment: Relevant [C11 6.7.2.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do enumerators work similar to macros internally ?

Somewhat yes, somewhat no.

> Will all these
> symbolic constants be replaced by there integer constants during
> preprocessing ?

No.  The preprocessor does not know one identifier from another, except those of preprocessing directives, the `defined` operator, and defined macro names.  You could try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO_TRUE 1
enum bool_enum { ENUM_FALSE = 0, ENUM_TRUE = 1 };

int main(void) {
#if MACRO_TRUE
    puts("Macro identifiers are known to the preprocessor.");
#else
    puts("Macro identifiers are not known to the preprocessor.");
#endif
#if ENUM_TRUE
    puts("Enum constants are known to the preprocessor.");
#else
    puts("Enum constants are not known to the preprocessor.");
#endif
}
```

The output should be

```
Macro identifiers are known to the preprocessor.
Enum constants are not known to the preprocessor.
```

> How exactly compiler handles them ?

In-scope enum constants are similar to other integer constants, such as `42`, except for the above caveat that they are not interpreted as such by the preprocessor.  They can be used in integer constant expressions, for example, which are required for various purposes such as in `case` labels in `switch` statements.  The standard does not specify details, but most compilers treat them similarly to macros in that no storage is reserved in the executable for them -- the source is treated as if enum constants were replaced by their corresponding integer values wherever they appear in expressions, *after* pre-processing.  Certainly they do not identify objects, in that they are not acceptable operands of the `&` operator.

This is to be distinguished from the behavior of `const`-qualified variables.  These identify actual objects, not mere constants.  They may not be used in constant expressions, and they do have storage associated with them (in the abstract machine, at least), so their addresses may be obtained via the `&` operator.

Comment: Your answer clears almost everything but just a basic doubt is still there. I am not able to understand if it is somehow internally treated as `const` variables than why they don't have storage associated with them. Also not related to this but can you please tell why exactly we can not use `const` variables in switch cases but we can comfortably do so with `enums` ?

Comment: @LocalHost, enum constants are *not* treated as `const` variables, as this answer already says.  `const`-qualified variables are not the same thing as "constants".  The specifics you are asking about -- whether there is associated storage, whether they can be used to form "constant expressions" -- are among the direct consequences of that distinction.  The language specifications say that constants, including enum constants, may appear in constant expressions, whereas object identifiers may not, `const` qualification notwithstanding.

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't work like macros, they rather work somehow like const variables.

So your code is very roughly equivalant to this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

const int sunday = 1, monday = 2, tuesday = 5, 
        wednesday = 6, thursday = 10, friday = 11, saturday = 12; 

int main() 
{ 
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", sunday, monday, tuesday, 
            wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Check it out here: https://www.godbolt.org/z/cErv5W

Comment: ... with the major exception that in `enum foo { sunday = 1 };` and `const int tuesday = 5;` the first is a compile-time constant, the 2nd one isn't. `switch (bar) { case sunday: /*ok*/; case tuesday: /*nope -- compiler error*/; }`

Comment: @pmg yes of course, I changed _roughly_ to _very roughly_

Comment: @Jabberwocky, the problem is not so much the "roughly", as it is the calling objects of type `const int` "constants".

Answer (score 1):

No, enums do not work like macros internally, enums are a data type that gets evaluated during compilation while macros get copied as text by the preprocessor.

from the gcc gnu documentation:
A macro is a fragment of code which has been given a name. Whenever the name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro. There are two kinds of macros. They differ mostly in what they look like when they are used. Object-like macros resemble data objects when used, function-like macros resemble function calls.

Enumeration is a user defined datatype in C language. It is used to assign names to the integral constants which makes a program easy to read and maintain. The keyword “enum” is used to declare an enumeration.

Comment: You are focusing on `enum` *types*, but the question is about enum *constants*.  There are indeed some similarities between these and object-like macros, and also some differences. Pretty much none of those are addressed in this answer.